# realloc an array of string

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

Currently, I have some confusion in realloc an array string. If I have this:

```
char** str = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));
str[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*7); //allocate a space for string size 7
//some other code that make the array full
```

My question is, if I want to realloc `str[0]` to size `8`, do I need to realloc both `str` and `str[0]` like this:

```
str = (char**)realloc(str,sizeof(char*)*101);
str[0] = (char*)realloc(str[0],sizeof(char)*8);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `realloc` the master array when you want to add a string (changing the *number of strings*). You `realloc` an individual string when you want to change that *string's length*.

Therefore, only `realloc` `str[0]` if you want to change the string's buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to reallocate the array of strings to lengthen the string at index zero. All you need is

```
str[0] = (char*)realloc(str[0],sizeof(char)*8);
```

Comment: why do I only need to realloc the str[0]? I think if I want to add size to str[0], while str already full, I have to realloc the whole thing. So, when do I need to realloc str? thx

Comment: The `str` array contains the string pointers - all 100 of them. The individual strings are allocated separately; the pointers to these strings are stored inside `str`. If you need more than 100 strings, you need to `realloc()` the `str`; if you need to increase the length of an individual string, you `realloc()` a `str[i]`.